# Detecting multiple touches WKInterfaceTable

Tags: ios, watchkit

Is there a way to detect if a table row has already been selected, right now I am protecting against multiple pushes with a boolean like so:

```
- (void)willActivate {
    // This method is called when watch view controller is about to be visible to user
    pushed=NO;
}

- (void)table:(WKInterfaceTable *)table didSelectRowAtIndex:(NSInteger)rowIndex {

    // if pushed, just return else continue and set pushed to true
    if (pushed) {
        return;
    }
    pushed=YES;

    [self pushControllerWithName:rowData[@"controllerIdentifier"] context:nil];
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Are users able to double-tap on the row and bring up two new controllers?

Comment: Yes, until the table disappears, you can push multiple instances of the new view controller on the view stack.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in method to detect multiple touches in a `WKInterfaceTable`. The technique that you're using is the same technique that I use in my Watch app. In my case, I maintain a BOOL for each row indicating whether it's enabled or not. Based on that BOOL, I updated my cell to show a "disabled"-looking state, though of course, it isn't technically disabled.